# Add or Remove Row in Input Table Along With Some Available Jinja

Tags: javascript, python, django, jinja2

I have an HTML table with some `jinja`(inside the `value` attribute).

my `template`:

```
<form class="" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
  <table class="table table-hover my-5">
    <thead class="">
        <tr>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>rank</th>
            <th>gmail</th>
            <th>Delete?</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="my_dynamic_table">
      {% for i in report_tableA %}
      <tr>
        <td>i</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="name" value="{{ i.name }}"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="rank" value="{{ i.rank }}"></td>
        <td><input type="email" name="gmail" value="{{ i.gmail }}"></td>
        <td><i class="fa fa-times-circle" style="font-size: 22px; color: red;"></i></td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div class="row mx-5">
    <button class="btn btn-warning">Add row</button>
    <button type="Submit" class="btn btn-primary ml-auto">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Now my problem is how can I implement the functionality of the `Add row` button and the `Delete` icon(inside last `td`)? Here `Add row` function will add a new row inside the table also with a `blank` `value` attribute.

I have practiced it before by the following [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65419407/add-or-remove-row-in-input-table). but now the problem is jinja is also added here.

I will be very grateful if you help me to fix this out.

Comment: Just empty value of appended row is that you want or something else?

Comment: yes that's what I want, and one more thing `removeRow` option for any row is also needed.

Comment: The link you have added in your question already does that ..it doesn't include `value` attribute when appending also it has remove functionality(the answer which is accepted) .

Comment: yes, but I cannot use it for some reason: now the value of `i` should come from the jinja..... and one more problem is also there like I need some row with `value="{{ i.something}}"` attribute. but the new `appended` row shouldn't have `value`.

Comment: can you use jquery here ?

Comment: Actually, I am a beginner and not familiar with js too much, I cannot understand how to perfectly code for this to fix it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first `clone` tr whenever `Add row` button is clicked then use `find("input").val("")` to empty *value* attribute and `find("td:eq(0)").text(length)` to add new `i` value to first `td` . Now , when *remove* is clicked then just use `.closest('tr')` this will get closest tr and remove that tr . Also, you need to adjust `i` value again inside your `td` so use `.each` loop to iterate through trs and change it.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(".add").on("click", function() {
  //get length of tr 
  var length = $(".my_dynamic_table tr").length + 1
  console.log(length)
  //clone first tr
  var cloned = $(".my_dynamic_table tr:first").clone();
  $(cloned).find("input").val(""); //empty values of all cloned inputs
  $(cloned).find("td:eq(0)").text(length); //add `i` value 
  $(cloned).appendTo($(".my_dynamic_table")) //append to tbody
})
//onclick of remove button
$(document).on("click", ".remove", function() {
  $(this).closest("tr").remove(); //remove tr
  //loop through tr
  $(".my_dynamic_table tr").each(function(i) {
    $(this).find("td:eq(0)").text((i + 1)) //change `i` value
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="" method="POST">
  <table class="table table-hover my-5">
    <thead class="">
      <tr>
        <th>No</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>rank</th>
        <th>gmail</th>
        <th>Delete?</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="my_dynamic_table">
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="name" value="{{ i.name }}"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="rank" value="{{ i.rank }}"></td>
        <td><input type="email" name="gmail" value="s@gmail.com"></td>
        <td><i class="fa fa-times-circle remove" style="font-size: 22px; color: red;">x</i></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div class="row mx-5">
    <button class="btn btn-warning add" type="button">Add row</button>
    <button type="Submit" class="btn btn-primary ml-auto">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, now it is working perfectly!